# How to install and use mirthSync on MacOS?

Tags: jar, clojure, mirth

## Setup

I'm following the [installation directions in the mirthSync readme](https://github.com/SagaHealthcareIT/mirthsync#installation), which is to clone the repo. The next indication of usage that I can see is in the [Examples section](https://github.com/SagaHealthcareIT/mirthsync#examples), which via CLI is to "pull Mirth Connect code from a Mirth Connect instance":

```
java -jar mirthsync.jar -s https://localhost:8443/api -u admin -p admin pull -t /home/user/
```

I'm assuming that after cloning the repo, one should `cd` into that directory and then run the `java -jar...` command with all the appropriate flag values (server, username, password, etc).

## Error

After running the CLI command, I get this error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile mirthsync.jar
```

## Question

Where is this `mirthsync.jar` file supposed to come from? Is there something I need to do in order to generate the `mirthsync.jar` file?

Comment: Generate it via `lein uberjar` or download it from a release.

Comment: yes, it's in the readme if you keep scrolling down to the **Build from Source** section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate it via `lein uberjar` (which creates `target/uberjar/*-standalone.jar`) or download it from a release.

Comment: Weird, I was expecting `lein uberjar` to generate mirthsync.jar in the root directory, but it created a "standalone" jar file that I was able to use successfully by providing the full path. `java -jar target/uberjar/mirthsync-2.1.0-standalone.jar -h`

Comment: No, everything ends up somewhere under `target` usually - also the "non-uberjar", which will not work out of the box (it only contains the local source and not the libs)